# Setting export location when using quick actions

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, illustrator-scripting, actions

I’m setting up some quick actions to improve my workflow, one is that I export a jpg of the artboard to a certain folder for each job I do.

ie. every job I do has a 3 folder directory, and my working file is in folder 2, but I export the jpg into folder 1. **Is there a way** (I believe might need to be scripted?) **to tell the action export to put the jpg into folder 1?** (So go up one level out of 2, then into 1?)

Those 3 folders are always named the same thing for every job, just the upper level folder is named per job.

Comment: Illustrator generally relies on *absolute* paths and I don't believe *actions* provide relative "walking" of any directory structure - i.e. there's no way to tell and *action* to back out of a directory. You can only tell the action what *specific* directory to use (by its absolute path). I *could*, of course, be incorrect. This is merely my experience with actions. You *can* perform "directory walking" via scripting though (javascript).

Comment: Unfortunately I assumed this would be the case. How would I go about working out the script needed for this?